# Combinatorics with friends and associates

Tags: combinatorics

In a company, each employee has at least two friends among the other employees. Now, call a friend of a
friend of an employee to be his/her *associate*.Initially, we have that all the employees are either friends or
associates. Moreover, if an even number (greater than $2$) of employees meet for a round table discussion, then
we can find two neighbouring members who are not friends.
Prove that, some friendships can be broken *owing to certain circumstances* such that, at the end, each
employee has exactly $1$ or $2$ friends.

A clearer definition of what an *associate* is, is given below:

Suppose the friends of an employee $E$ are denoted by $F_1, F_2, \ldots, F_n$. Pick a random employee $F_i$ for
some $i = 1,2,\ldots ,n$. If the friends of $F_i$, who are not friends with $E$ are denoted by $A_{i1} ,A_{i2}, \ldots ,A_{ik}$ ,
then we have that, each $A_{ij}$ for $j = 1, 2,\ldots, k$ is an associate of the employee E. Analogously, the
friends of each employee $A_{ij}$ who are not friends with employee $E$ are said to be $E$’s associates. We
can proceed on like this to any length of friends and associates.

**Source**: From a combinatorics book but with no solution ...

**Just to provide the Graph-Theoretical interpretation:** $G$ is a connected graph having no even cycles, initially with degree of each vertex $\geq 2$.
Prove that there is a spanning subgraph containing such that degree of each vertex is $1$ or $2$.

Comment: How are the associates involved? To answer that question: if the total number of employees is even, then you have pairs of employees that are friends. If the total number is odd, then you have 3 friends that are friends among each other (each employee has 2 friends)

Comment: Well we are actually given the information that ''initially all employees are either friends or associates'', so associates must be involved somewhere. In what you wrote, which friendships are broken?

Comment: I think the question is unclear/ill-stated. Initially it said that each employee had at least two friends. Now most employees will only have one friend.

Comment: Yes because what we are doing is to break some friendships. Initially why should each employee have at least two friends?

Comment: Some input of your own is expected, not just a bare question.

Comment: Well I know I have to post my progress or whatever, but this problem really got me stuck so I really don't know how to procced ...

Comment: You must have tried _something_. Showing an attempt (perhaps indicating the obstacles) may defend against the problem being closed.

Comment: Also, for context, you should indicate the source (i.e., what book?).

Comment: Well, for the source, it is from a Greek Book (written by 4 different authors). Anyway, if you want to close the topic, do it. I just asked a problem I could not solve or approach (i am not thaaaaaaaaaaaaat good at combo anyway) and the only think I am learning is that you are not keen to help me.

Comment: I added the graph-theoretical interpretation of the problem. Could someone help me now? @quasi can you help me?

Comment: Your edit shows at least _some_ effort, so it's better than nothing. In your graph-theoretic interpretation, don't you also need to specify that the diameter is at most $2$?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Any solution/idea now?

Comment: I'm thinking about it.

Comment: Okay. Any help is welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: It was wrong, sorry (I'm a little tired).

Comment: Ah ok, seems to be a hard problem anyway.

Comment: Any progress on that?

Comment: In what way is my answer unsatisfactory, @math_here ?

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem.** If $G$ is a finite graph with minimum degree at least $2$ and no even cycles, then $G$ has a spanning subgraph in which every vertex has degree $1$ or $2$.

A more general formulation:

**Theorem.** If $G$ is a finite graph with no even cycles, then $G$ has a spanning subgraph $H$ such that every vertex, which has degree at least $2$ in $G$, has degree either $1$ or $2$ in $H$.

**Proof.** If there are any edges joining two vertices of degree greater than $2$, delete one such edge. Repeat until there is no edge joining two vertices of degree greater than $2$. We still have a graph with no even cycles, and every vertex which initially had degree at least $2$ still has degree at least $2$.

Now let $X$ be the set of vertices of degree $\gt2$ and let $Y$ be the set of vertices of degree $\le2$; so $X$ is an independent set. Let $F$ be the bipartite subgraph of $G$ consisting of edges joining a vertex in $X$ to a vertex in $Y$. Since $G$ has no even cycles, $F$ is an acyclic graph, i.e., a forest; each connected component of $F$ is a tree. For each nontrivial component $T$ of $F$, choose some vertex in $V(T)\cap Y$ as the root, and direct all edges of $T$ towards the root. With this orientation of the subgraph $F$, every vertex has outdegree at most $1$, and every vertex in $X$ has outdegree equal to $1$.

Finally, remove from $G$ all those edges of $F$ which are directed from $Y$ to $X$. Now each vertex in $X$ has degree exactly $1$. Each vertex in $Y$ loses at most one edge, so its degree is at least $1$ if it was initially at least $2$; and of course it is at most $2$.

The following more general statement can be proved in the same way:

**Theorem.** If $G$ is a finite graph with no even cycles, and if $n$ is a positive integer, then $G$ has a spanning subgraph $H$ such that every vertex, which has degree at least $n$ in $G$, has degree $1$ or $n-1$ or $n$ in $H$.